# MimeMessage shows empty body in email in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, mime-types, mimekit, mime-message, mime-mail

I want to show html body in mail, I was sending mail through SMTP server using windows service. I write the request in a file & pass this file to MIME.Load() method to read that file and extract the data from that file, but here I get body in plain text format, & so empty body shows when actual email sent. I code for this as below, I use C# for coding

```
var message = MimeMessage.Load(emailFile);
```

I have html body but when I checked this message it gives me only plain text and does not shows its html version. I don't understand here how to set or change plain text body to html body in Mime. Does anyone knows about the solution. Thanks

Comment: I would need to see the raw message to help you.

Comment: My doubt has solved now. Thank you